# TypeError: change.after.val is not a function firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi there I am trying to read changes in my firestore database

```
'use stricts'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendOrderCompletionEmail = functions.firestore.document('/service-requests/{req_id}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const req = context.params.req_id;
            
        const sts = change.after.val();  //Error on this line
                
        console.log(sts);
                
    });
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: change.after.val is not a function
```

I want to read changes in my document and return the field value which is changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are triggering your Cloud Function by the update of a Firestore document, you need to do

```
const sts = change.after.data();
```

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated) for more details.

---

As a matter of fact we use the `val()` method for Cloud Functions triggered by a [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value) event.

Firebase offers two NoSQL database solutions: Cloud Firestore and the Realtime Database. See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore) for more details.